# running EFI shell commands on windows command line

Tags: windows, shell, uefi, mbr2gpt

I need to run EFI shell commands to get the directory listing of EFI partition.
Do i need to install some tool on my system(windows).
How can i run EFI shell commands on windows?

Comment: The EFI shell can't run after an OS has booted. But Windows should be able to mount the EFI partition and access it using normal Windows commands.

Comment: Can we list down files/directories present in EFI partition like we do for other partitions. If yes , how?

Comment: can we access the partiton related details if machine is not booting up ?

Answer (score 1):

We can access the EFI system partition by mounting it to some drive letter.

1) run `diskpart`

2) select disk on which the EFI partition system is present (eg: sel disk 0)

3) select EFI partition (eg. sel part 1)

4) assign drive letter (eg.assign letter=h)

5) exit